# Debugging excess GC time in ocaml

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, ocaml, profiling

I have written an OCaml implementation of B-trees. It is slow, and takes ~1 minute to add about 100k small ~16 byte records. When I profiled the implementation, I discovered that the program is spending most (~58 seconds) of its time in garbage collection.

The specific functions are:

```
   caml_garbage_collection, which consumes 58 seconds, of this:

   caml_major_collection_slice consumes 63% and
   caml_gc_dispatch consumes 23.5%
```

What could be the cause of this overactive garbage collection, and how would I go about debugging it?

Comment: How did you do the profiling? In my experience the standard Unix profiling tools do not cope well with higher order functions.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this problem by using Spacetime, a memory profiler for OCaml, and by following the instructions here: https://blog.janestreet.com/a-brief-trip-through-spacetime/

It was a very smooth experience. I identified the issue to be a debugging data structure. I was keeping a list of the entries around as a mutable reference to a list, which I was updating as follows:

`t.orig_items <- new_entry :: t.orig_items`

It appears that when you do this, OCaml creates a copy of the original list. So using a mutable list in this way is a bad idea, it seems.

Comment: There's no such thing in OCaml as a mutable list. What you have here is an immutable list that you assign to a mutable record field. Also, while prepending an item to a list, as you do here, does allocate a new cons cell, it reuses the rest of the list (since it's immutable). This therefore won't cause any garbage to be collected, and so I doubt this operation specifically is the problem. I'm sure you use this list in other ways elsewhere though, which might very well be problematic, but this in itself shouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke there, I meant a mutable reference to a list. Editing.